# How can I prevent the overwriting of an implicit user image in this Firebase 9 app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am making a chat app with React 18 and Firebase 9.

In the *Register* form, I have an input of type file, for uploading  user's *avatar*.

The `avatar` form field is *optional* and there is a `default-avatar.png` file that I uploaded manually in Storage and is intended for as *default user image*.

In `Register.jsx` I have:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import md5 from "md5";
import FormCard from "../components/FormCard/FormCard";
import Success from "../components/Alerts/Success";
import Error from "../components/Alerts/Error";
import { make, register } from "simple-body-validator";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
import { ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { auth, db, storage } from "../firebaseConfig";

// Custom validation rule
register('image-only', function (value) {
  let allowedFormats = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png"];
  let format = value.name.split('.')[1].toLowerCase();
  return allowedFormats.includes(format);
}, function() {
  return "Only JPG, JPEG, and PNG files are allowed.";
});

export default function Register() {
  const initialFormData = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    avatar: "",
    password: "",
    password_confirmation: ""
  };

  const validationRules = {
    firstName: ["required", "string", "min:3", "max:255"],
    lastName: ["required", "string", "min:3", "max:255"],
    email: ["required", "email"],
    avatar: ["image-only"],
    password: ["required", "min:6", "confirmed"],
    password_confirmation: ["required"]
  };

  const validator = make(initialFormData, validationRules);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialFormData);

  // Form validation errors
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState(validator.errors());
  // Firebase errors
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  const [pristineFields, setPristineFields] = useState(() =>
    Object.keys(initialFormData)
  );

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value, files } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => {
      const newValue = files?.length > 0 ? files[0] : value;
      const newFormData = { ...prevFormData, [name]: newValue };
      const newPristineFields = pristineFields.filter((f) => f !== name);

      validator.setData(newFormData).validate();
      const validationErrors = validator.errors();
      newPristineFields.forEach((f) => validationErrors.forget(f));
      setErrors(validationErrors);

      setPristineFields(newPristineFields);

      return newFormData;
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!validator.setData(formData).validate()) {
      setErrors(validator.errors());
    } else {

      const email = formData.email;
      const password = formData.password;
      const successContainer = document.getElementById('successAlert');
      const errContainer = document.getElementById('errorAlert');

      try {
        const response = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
        // Hide error
        errContainer.classList.add('d-none');

        // Show success
        successContainer.classList.remove('d-none');

        // Create avatar filename
        const meta = { contentType: 'image/jpeg, image/png' };
        const date = new Date().getTime();
        let userAvatar = formData.avatar
          ? md5(`${formData.email}-${date}`) + '.' + formData.avatar.name.split(".")[1]
          : "default-avatar.png";
        const storageRef = ref(storage, userAvatar);

        // Upload image
        await uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, formData.avatar, meta).then(() => {
          getDownloadURL(storageRef).then(async (url) => {
            try {
              // Update profile
              await updateProfile(response.user, {
                avatar: url,
              });

              // Store user
              await setDoc(doc(db, "users", response.user.uid), {
                uid: response.user.uid,
                firstName: formData.firstName,
                lastName: formData.lastName,
                email: formData.email,
                avatar: userAvatar,
              });
            } catch (error) {
              setError(true);
              console.log(error)
            }
          })
        })

      } catch (error) {
        setError(true);
        errContainer.append(error.message);
        errContainer.classList.remove('d-none');
      }
    }

    setPristineFields([]);
  };

  return (
    <FormCard title="Register">

      {/* Alerts */}
      <Error dismissible={true} error={error} />
      <Success dismissible={true} message="You have registered successfully. You can sign in!" />

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div
          className={`mb-2 form-element ${errors.has("email") ? "has-error" : null
            }`}
        >
          <label for="email" className="form-label">
            Email address
          </label>
          <input
            type="email"
            id="email"
            name="email"
            value={formData.email}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className="form-control form-control-sm"
          />
          {errors.has("email") ? (
            <p className="invalid-feedback">{errors.first("email")}</p>
          ) : null}
        </div>

        <div
          className={`mb-2 form-element ${errors.has("avatar") ? "has-error" : null
            }`}
        >
          <label for="avatar" className="form-label">
            Avatar
          </label>
          <input
            type="file"
            id="avatar"
            name="avatar"
            onChange={handleChange}
            className="form-control form-control-sm"
          />
          {errors.has("avatar") ? (
            <p className="invalid-feedback">{errors.first("avatar")}</p>
          ) : null}
        </div>

        <div className="pt-1">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-sm btn-success fw-bold">
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </FormCard>
  );
}
```

#### The problem

If the user does not upload an avatar, the image I uploaded manually in Storage (`default-avatar.png`) is overwritten by an *empty image*.

#### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What is the most reliable way to fix the issue?

Comment: Why do we want to upload `default-avatar.png` every time? Upload it once and get the download url. Just skip if the user hasn't selected the image and store the download url in the profile.

Comment: @ShriHariL I _don't_ want to upload default-avatar.png every time. I want to upload it once (manually) and add the _filename only_ to the user if the user does not explicitly pick an avatar. I want to "skip", but _only the file upload_, in other words. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem: When users do not upload an avatar during registration, the manually uploaded image (`default-avatar.png`) in Storage is overwritten by an empty image.

Solution: To maintain `default-avatar.png` if no avatar is uploaded, modify the avatar assignment logic to set `userAvatar` to the default value when no avatar is provided.

Your code:

```js
let userAvatar = formData.avatar ? md5(`${formData.email}-${date}`) + '.' + formData.avatar.name.split(".")[1]
  : "default-avatar.png";
```

Solution Code:

```js
let userAvatar = formData.avatar ? md5(`${formData.email}-${date}`) + '.' + formData.avatar.name.split(".")[1] : formData.avatar || "default-avatar.png";
```

Explanation:

If `formData.avatar` is provided, a unique avatar name based on email and date is generated.
If no avatar is uploaded (`formData.avatar` is `falsy`), it checks for `formData.avatar`, and if that's also falsy (no avatar provided), it defaults to `"default-avatar.png"` to ensure the default avatar is used.
This change ensures that `default-avatar.png` is used if no user avatar is uploaded.

here is the perfect solution of your issue

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (!validator.setData(formData).validate()) {
    setErrors(validator.errors());
  } else {
    const email = formData.email;
    const password = formData.password;
    const successContainer = document.getElementById('successAlert');
    const errContainer = document.getElementById('errorAlert');

    try {
      const response = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      // Hide error
      errContainer.classList.add('d-none');

      // Show success
      successContainer.classList.remove('d-none');

      let userAvatar = "default-avatar.png"; // Default avatar image

      // Check if the user uploaded an avatar
      if (formData.avatar) {
        // Create avatar filename
        const meta = { contentType: 'image/jpeg, image/png' };
        const date = new Date().getTime();
        userAvatar = md5(`${formData.email}-${date}`) + '.' + formData.avatar.name.split(".")[1];

        const storageRef = ref(storage, userAvatar);

        // Upload image
        await uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, formData.avatar, meta);
      }

      // Get download URL (either uploaded avatar or default avatar)
      const avatarURL = await getDownloadURL(ref(storage, userAvatar));

      try {
        // Update profile
        await updateProfile(response.user, {
          avatar: avatarURL,
        });

        // Store user
        await setDoc(doc(db, "users", response.user.uid), {
          uid: response.user.uid,
          firstName: formData.firstName,
          lastName: formData.lastName,
          email: formData.email,
          avatar: userAvatar,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        setError(true);
        console.log(error);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setError(true);
      errContainer.append(error.message);
      errContainer.classList.remove('d-none');
    }
  }

  setPristineFields([]);
};
```

Explanation:
In this modified code, we first set the `userAvatar` to the default avatar image. If the user uploads an avatar, we update userAvatar to the filename generated for the uploaded avatar. Then, we proceed to upload the avatar (if provided) and store the user information with the correct avatar filename.

Comment: I trayed your solution, but it does not work, apatently.

Comment: Here is the steps, first we added error handling, Introduced a variable "userAvatar" to handle the avatar filename, initially set to the default avatar image (default-avatar.png).
Checked if the user uploaded an avatar (formData.avatar). If uploaded, generated a unique filename based on email and timestamp, updating userAvatar.
Conditionally uploaded the avatar using the generated filename or skipped the upload if no avatar was provided.
Ensured the correct avatar filename (either uploaded or default) was used for updating the user's profile and storing user information in the database

Comment: Have you seen the codebox I linked?

Comment: yes, I have visited the code, let me know, if this solution couldn't work for you

Comment: Has the problem been resolved?

Answer (score -2):

You are still attempting to upload and overwrite the default-avatar.png file in storage with an empty file

```
let userAvatar = formData.avatar
  ? md5(`${formData.email}-${date}`) + '.' + formData.avatar.name.split(".")[1]
  : "default-avatar.png";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).